# Checkstyle avoid of logging files without error

Tags: properties, checkstyle

I want to know how to avoid logging of files without errors.
Here is the example of report:

```
<file name="/applications/comp/Editor.java"></file>
<file name="/applications/comp/Component.java">
    <error line="73" severity="warning" message="Line is longer than 120 characters (found 271)." source="com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.sizes.LineLengthCheck"/>
</file>
```

Is there a way to ignore filename Editor.java which doesn't have erros ?

Comment: Do you want such report to be generated out-of-the-box or solutions using  post-processing are also OK?

Comment: There is a difference between files that were not checked and files that were checked but did not have errors. That's information I wouldn't want to lose.